# Vue 2 add class active through exploring list

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

i have problem with input and lists, I would like to go through from input to list element below and add class 'active' to current li element

```
<div class="control">
      <label class="label">Input Test</label>
      <input type="text" class="input" @keydown="keyHandler">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="suggestion in suggestions" v-bind:class="{active}">{{suggestion.message}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

methods : {
    keyHandler(e){
        if(e.keyCode === 38){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('arrow up')
        this.currentKey = e.key
      }
      else if(e.keyCode === 40){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('arrow down')
        this.currentKey = e.key
      }
    }   
  }
```

here is fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o8fwf0gh/13/

I would be grateful for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#form',
  data: {
    currentKey: null,
    suggestions: [{
      message: 'Foo'
    }, {
      message: 'Bar'
    }, {
      message: 'Foobar'
    }, {
      message: 'pikachu'
    }, {
      message: 'raichu'
    }],
    active: false
  },
  methods: {
    keyHandler(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 38) {
          e.preventDefault();
          console.log('arrow up')
          this.setActiveClass(this.currentKey, e.key)
          this.currentKey = e.key
        } else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
          e.preventDefault();
          this.setActiveClass(this.currentKey, e.key)
          console.log('arrow down')
          this.currentKey = e.key
        }
      },
      setActiveClass(previousKey, currentKey) {
        if (previousKey) {
          var tempIndex = this.suggestions.findIndex(x => x.class ==     "active");
          this.$set(this.suggestions[tempIndex], 'class', 'inactive')
          if (currentKey === 'ArrowDown') {
            if (tempIndex === this.suggestions.length - 1)
              this.$set(this.suggestions[0], 'class', 'active')
            else
              this.$set(this.suggestions[tempIndex + 1], 'class', 'active')
          } else {
            if (tempIndex === 0)
              this.$set(this.suggestions[this.suggestions.length - 1], 'class', 'active')
            else
              this.$set(this.suggestions[tempIndex - 1], 'class',     'active')
          }
        } else {
          if(currentKey === 'ArrowUp')
            this.$set(this.suggestions[this.suggestions.length - 1], 'class', 'active')
          else
            this.$set(this.suggestions[0], 'class', 'active')
          }
        }
      }
  }
})
```

and in HTML you can do the following:

```
<li v-for="suggestion in suggestions" v-bind:class='suggestion.class'>{{suggestion.message}}
```

Working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/o8fwf0gh/17/)

Comment: That is perfect! Thanks

Comment: could you tell me how to change your fiddle when the data is suggestions: [
    'Foo', 
    'Bar', 
    'Foobar', 
    'pikachu', 
    'raichu'],  here is fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o8fwf0gh/19/ I get the "Cannot create property 'class' on string" error

Comment: The method I have used works only when you have array of objects. Now you have changed it to array of strings. So solution does not hold for your new requirement.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is update a data property, let's say `selected`, with where you should be in the list. By default we'll set it on 0, so that the first element is selected:

```
data: {
    selected: 0,
    // other data stuff
}
```

When pressing the up or down arrow you obviously have to update this.selected as such:

```
methods : {
keyHandler(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 38){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.selected--;
    }
    else if(e.keyCode === 40){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.selected++;
    }
}
```

}

You can then set up your list as such:

```
<li v-for="(suggestion, index) in suggestions" :class="index === selected ? 'active' : ''">{{suggestion.message}}</li>
```

What you see inside the class property is know as shorthand syntax. It's basically an if statement that returns 'active' if the index is equal to the list-number that is currently selected. As you can see the index is passed along as a second property inside v-for.

This should do the trick, if I understood correctly what you're trying to achieve. :P